# Git - disable custom filters when stashing

Tags: git, filtering, git-stash

I've got a custom filter in `.git/config` to remove lines marked: `# todo`.

```
[filter "removetodo"]
    clean = "sed '/\\ *#\\ todo/d'"
```

Plus `*.py filter=removetodo` in file `.gitattributes`.

Works nice, I can use `git add -p` without looking at a lot of my temporary comments (I don't commit TODOs in code).

But **when I have to stash changes, those lines are dropped.** `git stash pop` gives me those files without the filtered out lines. How to fix this behavior so filters are disabled when stashing?

Answer (score 2):

```
git -c filter.removetodo.clean=cat stash
```

should do it.

Comment: Since you'd want to do this every time you stash, you probably should look into creating an alias, though...